# Do extra parentheses in conditions make any sense?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with some older JavaScript code and stumbled upon the widely use of extra parentheses in conditions like so:

```
if ((foo)) { /* ... */ }

if (!(bar)) { /* ... */ }

if ((lorem === 'ipsum')) { /* ... */ }

if ((functionCall1()) || (functionCall2())) { /* ... */}
```

Does this practice make any sense? Am I unaware of a bug in an older javascript implementation?

Comment: You only need to do this if you are using multiple `AND` and `OR` together, since you need to group them for the code to understand what you mean.

Comment: That practice does not make any sense, in my opinion. There is no associated bug with using parenthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra parentheses in these examples serve no purpose at all.

This code functions ***exactly*** the same, and is (arguably) more readable:

```
if (foo) { /* ... */ }

if (!bar) { /* ... */ }

if (lorem === 'ipsum') { /* ... */ }

if (functionCall1() || functionCall2()) { /* ... */}
```

There is literally no point in adding them.

Comment: It is exactly the readability that was on my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No they are entirely superfluous.

Some folk like to add excess parentheses in order to achieve a sense of clarity in their expressions: particularly when working with `&&`, `||`, and the ternary conditional operator  `? :`.

Personally I *never* do that as I only using parentheses when absolutely necessary. To me parentheses signal that an expression needs to depart from normal operator precedences for it to evaluate correctly. One instance is when working with `<<` and `>>` which, for some reason, have surprisingly low precedence.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's overkill. Any minifier would get rid of it.

On a related note, there's a special case where the extra parentheses actually make a difference, but it's only in this case:

```
(function() { /* Do something */ })();
```

That's right, a common IIFE. And that's due to JS engines preemptively optimizing this kind of function calls.

There's a [library](https://github.com/nolanlawson/optimize-js) to actually exploit this. I don't recommend to used it, though, since it's, well, an exploit and might not work in the future.

Comment: Im aware of that expression and use it regulary for namespacing.